# Remove '\n' from List and make string to each element in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list like this:

```
newContents = ['All Spekit Users\nSpekit Account Admins\nTesting Team 28']
```

But I want my list like this:

```
newContents = ['All Spekit Users', 'Spekit Account Admins', 'Testing Team 28']
```

How Can I acheive this

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
>>> newContents = ['All Spekit Users\nSpekit Account Admins\nTesting Team 28']
>>> newContents[0].split("\n")
['All Spekit Users', 'Spekit Account Admins', 'Testing Team 28']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use splitlines to split string.

```py
newContents = ['All Spekit Users\nSpekit Account Admins\nTesting Team 28']
replaceContent = []
for n in newContents:
    replaceContent.append(n.splitlines())

print(replaceContent)
```

> [['All Spekit Users', 'Spekit Account Admins', 'Testing Team 28']]